# Looking for a DEM elevation model for entire UK - not in tile form

Tags: data-request, geospatial

I need to calculate the elevation of 1600 survey plots covering all of the UK - I have these formatted as a point shapefile. I have looked at the OS50 dataset but this is only available as tiles and it would take forever to process each tile individually - my points cover the entire country. Is there free-to-use raster elevation data anywhere that is not split into many tiles?

I have read several questions on here relating to sourcing elevation data and I also downloaded the Environment Agency LIDAR composite dtm dataset - but this does not appear to contain any asc or tiff files so I can't get a raster from it. I just want a simple calc of elevation for all these plots without having to process many individual tiles.

Comment: it doesn't take long to stitch the OS tiles together - just unpack and build a VRT of each tile and then process them together

Comment: I'm guessing SRTM1 (1 arcsecond resolution) isn't fine enough for your needs?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Copernicus Digital Elevation Model covering Europe at different spatial resolutions from here (GeoTIFF files):

https://data.mundialis.de/geonetwork/srv/eng/catalog.search#/search?keyword=Copernicus

For the download links, see the respective Zenodo DOI entries therein.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested only in elevation data, there is no need to download and process large TIFFs thanks to [`elevatr`](https://github.com/jhollist/elevatr) package.

Let's get some species occurrence data from GBIF as example. *Calystegia pulchra,* from GB territory.

```
occ <- rgbif::occ_data(scientificName = "Calystegia pulchra", 
          country = "GB", hasCoordinate = TRUE)
```

In next step let's take first 20 rows and convert it to `sf` data frame with POINT coordinates.

```
occ <- head(occ$data, 20) |>
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c("decimalLongitude", "decimalLatitude"), 
    crs = sf::st_crs(4326)) |>
  subset(select = c("key", "scientificName"))
```

And finally let's add the elevation using `mutate` from `dplyr` package:

```
occ |>
  dplyr::mutate(ele = elevatr::get_elev_point(geometry, src = "aws"))
#> Mosaicing & Projecting
#> Note: Elevation units are in meters
#> Simple feature collection with 20 features and 3 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -6.19056 ymin: 51.49552 xmax: -0.17902 ymax: 57.42103
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#> # A tibble: 20 × 4
#>    key        scientificName                                  geometry ele$elevation $elev_units            $geometry
#>  * <chr>      <chr>                                        <POINT [°]>         <dbl> <chr>                <POINT [°]>
#>  1 3320924569 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood  (-0.17902 51.49553)            15 meters       (-0.17902 51.49553)
#>  2 3437494613 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-1.962333 51.78564)           191 meters      (-1.962333 51.78564)
#>  3 3785877810 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood  (-2.541045 52.5979)           169 meters       (-2.541045 52.5979)
#>  4 3352641836 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-6.189535 57.41207)            44 meters      (-6.189535 57.41207)
#>  5 3338086543 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-2.302697 53.20301)            75 meters      (-2.302697 53.20301)
#>  6 3352720276 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood  (-3.052632 54.8225)            81 meters       (-3.052632 54.8225)
#>  7 3352736637 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-1.614114 55.37932)            19 meters      (-1.614114 55.37932)
#>  8 3384449063 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-4.681922 57.14801)            78 meters      (-4.681922 57.14801)
#>  9 3421262904 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood  (-6.19056 57.42103)            75 meters       (-6.19056 57.42103)
#> 10 3392248456 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-6.159327 56.11731)            12 meters      (-6.159327 56.11731)
#> 11 3437541839 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-1.962333 51.78564)           191 meters      (-1.962333 51.78564)
#> 12 2641626771 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood  (-2.82636 53.56805)            46 meters       (-2.82636 53.56805)
#> 13 2988497510 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-2.094492 53.71386)           244 meters      (-2.094492 53.71386)
#> 14 3057847359 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood  (-2.83544 52.59035)           273 meters       (-2.83544 52.59035)
#> 15 3384377467 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood           (-2.34 53)           125 meters                (-2.34 53)
#> 16 2907372606 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-1.962333 51.78564)           191 meters      (-1.962333 51.78564)
#> 17 3115794572 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood  (-5.405346 56.4888)            32 meters       (-5.405346 56.4888)
#> 18 3785862074 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-2.762203 52.38906)            92 meters      (-2.762203 52.38906)
#> 19 3115792727 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-5.403569 56.49253)            32 meters      (-5.403569 56.49253)
#> 20 2868245139 Calystegia pulchra Brumm. & Heywood (-2.520677 56.59051)            35 meters      (-2.520677 56.59051)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Regards,
Grzegorz